# Overly complicated manipulation of types

Tags: vb.net

I need a small static data tree in which each member can have some variables or contain child members

I figured I'd try building it like this

```
Public Class nBase
    Public Shared Name As String
    Public Shared Description As String

    Public Class nFruit
        Inherits nBase
        Shared Sub New()
            Name = "Fruit" : Description = "Grows on trees"
        End Sub
        Public Class nApple
            Inherits nFruit
            Shared Sub New()
                Name = "Apple" : Description = "I'm an apple!"
            End Sub
        End Class

    End Class
    Public Class nVegetable
        Inherits nBase
        Shared Sub New()
            Name = "Vegetable" : Description = "does the tomato belong here?"
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

And then an example of practical application

```
Public Sub makestock()

    Dim Stock As New Dictionary(Of Type, Integer)
    Stock.Add(GetType(nBase.nFruit), 2)
    Stock.Add(GetType(nBase.nFruit.nApple), 5)
    Stock.Add(GetType(nBase.nVegetable), 2)


End Sub
```

So here I declare that my stock consists of 5 apples, 2 vegetables and 2 fruit(note: the amount of apples isn't counted among the fruit because in my context it just means that the type of fruit isn't defined so the total is 7 fruits among which are 5 apples and 2 undefined)

Now maybe theres a GUI function that wants to know the description of the stock keys so I do

```
Dim description = Activator.CreateInstance(Stock.Keys(0)).Description
```

Great. That is all I need from this "database". However, as you may have noticed, its really rather clunky on the usage end of things. Here's what I'd consider ideal:

```
Stock.add(nBase.nFruit, 2)
Dim description = Stock.Keys(0).Description
```

(yes, I know that doesn't work, imaginary code). Are there any methods by which I could get closer to my ideal? Just so the whole thing would be less of a pain to write...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by changing the list to store objects rather than types, each object containing instance properties.  Then you can have shared properties on the base type to expose some singleton instances of the various derived types:

```
Public Class nBase
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Description As String

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Fruit As New nFruit()
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Apple As New nFruit.nApple()
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Vegetable As New nVegetable()

    Public Class nFruit
        Inherits nBase
        Public Sub New()
            Name = "Fruit" : Description = "Grows on trees"
        End Sub

        Public Class nApple
            Inherits nFruit
            Public Sub New()
                Name = "Apple" : Description = "I'm an apple!"
            End Sub
        End Class
    End Class

    Public Class nVegetable
        Inherits nBase
        Public Sub New()
            Name = "Vegetable" : Description = "does the tomato belong here?"
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class

' ...

Dim stock As New Dictionary(Of nBase, Integer)()
stock.Add(nBase.Fruit, 2)
Dim description = Stock.Keys(0).Description
```

However, it's worth pointing out that there's really no need to nest them.  The inheritance works regardless of how the classes are nested.  For instance, you could just have them all be not nested:

```
Public Class nBase
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Description As String

    Public ReadOnly Property Fruit As New nFruit()
    Public ReadOnly Property Apple As New nApple()
    Public ReadOnly Property Vegetable As New nVegetable()
End Class

Public Class nFruit
    Inherits nBase
    Public Sub New()
        Name = "Fruit" : Description = "Grows on trees"
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class nApple
    Inherits nFruit
    Public Sub New()
        Name = "Apple" : Description = "I'm an apple!"
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class nVegetable
    Inherits nBase
    Public Sub New()
        Name = "Vegetable" : Description = "does the tomato belong here?"
    End Sub
End Class
```

### Update

Based on your comments below, you could do something like this:

```
Public Class nBase
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Description As String

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Fruit As New nFruit()
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Vegetable As New nVegetable()

    Public Class nFruit
        Inherits nBase
        Public Sub New()
            Name = "Fruit" : Description = "Grows on trees"
        End Sub

        Public ReadOnly Property Apple As New nApple()

        Public Class nApple
            Inherits nFruit
            Public Sub New()
                Name = "Apple" : Description = "I'm an apple!"
            End Sub
        End Class
    End Class

    Public Class nVegetable
        Inherits nBase
        Public Sub New()
            Name = "Vegetable" : Description = "does the tomato belong here?"
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class

' ...

Dim stock As New Dictionary(Of nBase, Integer)()
stock.Add(nBase.Fruit, 2)
stock.Add(nBase.Fruit.Apple, 5)
stock.Add(nBase.Vegetable, 2)
Dim description As String = stock.Keys(0).Description
```

Comment: That works, however, in your snippet you have the instance objects flattened in the nBase class. I want them in a tree shape (since there is quite a few) so I instead put the Apple property inside the nFruit class. Accessing the apple through the fruit gives me a warning though "Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated." and Apple doesn't even want to show up under nBase.Fruit. The code works regardless but I'm wondering if this warning could turn into an error at some point..?